# Java GUI import textfile data to a JTable

Tags: java, arrays, swing, vector, file-handling

I am writing a program, for my assignment, which should get some user input data from GUI(jtextfield) to a textfile and then retrive those data from the textfile to another GUI(JTable).

I have some basic knowledge about the file handling and JAVA swing, and I get some problems now.

First of all, please let me tell what I have done now (code below).

1. appending the data

```java
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        //once clicked the button write the file
        Object[] cols = new Object[]{
                model.getText(),
                make.getText(),
                year.getText()
        };

        try {

            FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream("words.txt", true);
            ObjectOutputStream outputFile = new ObjectOutputStream(fstream);

            outputFile.writeObject(cols);


            //bw.close();
            outputFile.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

2. Reading the data from the word file to Jtable

```java
public class read extends JFrame {

    JTable table = new JTable();
    JScrollPane pane;
    Object[] cols = null;
    
    public read() throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        
        cols = new String[]{"c1", "c2", "c3",};

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();

        model.setColumnIdentifiers(cols);

        File f = new File("words.txt");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Object[] data = (Object[]) ois.readObject();
        model.addRow(data);
        
        pane = new JScrollPane(table);
        pane.setBounds(100, 150, 300, 300);
        
        setLayout(null);
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setSize(500, 500);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        new read();
    }
}
```

It's working now but it only retrive one piece of data from the file, I want it to show all the data added to the file.

My questions are:

1. My words file looks like different:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbIVk.png]

and I am not sure if it just me or it just what it should be? Because I am expecting that it should be exact what I write, so even the addrow(object) method is not working I can add row using getline.

2. (Important) Because I write multible different data to the words file(and its shown in the image above), but it only shows one.
   I assume that is because I should add an array of objects to the table in read.java instead of just addrow(object) but i dont know how, I mean I  dont know how to let the array recognise that there are a lot of  objects in the words file. also, is it okay to write the data as object to the file and retrive them in the read.java, is it a proper way?

Can someone tell me how, thanks fore your help.
Please don't hesitate to ask if I didn't state it properly.

Comment: 1) `outputFile.close();` should be `outputFile.flush(); outputFile.close();` 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *but it only shows one.* - well you would need a loop to read all objects.

Comment: 3) `Object[] data = (Object[]) ois.readObject(); model.addRow(data);` these should be done in a loop. Something like `Object[] data = (Object[]) ois.readObject(); while(data!=null) { model.addRow(data); data = (Object[]) ois.readObject(); }`

Comment: 1) What you mean with different? You are serializing Objects, this will result in binary files, do not expect readable files when using this feature. If you want to produce and read text files better use a CSV library in this case 2) You read only one object of type array in your code, if you want to read more use a loop, add your objects to a list and add all to the table model

Comment: i am not really sure if i serialized the object cuz i didnt implemet it in main, or it is serialized because i used  FileInputStream or ObjectInputStream? @ Rocco

Comment: thx andrew. can i knwo whats the difference bewteen outputFile.close(); and outputFile.flush(); outputFile.close();? also for the edit to add, do you mean to add a tag or something? i am new to here:)

Comment: @caoyu *i am not really sure if i serialized the object* - read the API for ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: The difference is in the addition of `outputFile.flush();`. Have you read the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush()) on the method? This is something a programmer should do with any line of Java API code we are trying to understand.